# PHP - foreach array loop. hide last 50% of the array using counter

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have some code like this.

```
$counter = 1;
$content = "";
foreach($images as $image) {
    $content .= "<li><img src='".$image['images_image'][1]['thumb']."'></li>";
    $counter++;
}
echo apply_filters('images_filter', $content);
```

The above code hides the whole content by using WordPress filters. But I would like to hide only the last 50% of images.

Let's say I have 15 images.

```
$hide = floor( $counter / 2 ); //value will be 7
```

So I would like to hide only images from 8 to 15.

I've tried like this. But it's not working.

```
if ($counter >= $hide) {
    echo apply_filters('images_filter', $content);
}
```

Can someone tell me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the image filter, but this should work:

```
  $show = ceil( count($images) / 2 );      
  $counter = 1;
  $content = "";
  foreach($images as $image){
        if($counter<=$show){
            $content .= "<li><img src='".$image['images_image'][1]['thumb']."'></li>";
        }else{
            break;
        }
        ++$counter;
     }
    echo apply_filters('images_filter',$content);
```

Comment: This will add only the images to show to content, and will then stop the loop using break to save a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$counter = 1;
$content = "";
$hide = floor( $counter / 2 ); //value will be 7
foreach($images as $image){

    if ($counter >= $hide) $content .= "<li><img src='".$image['images_image'][1]['thumb']."'></li>";
    else echo "<li><img src='".$image['images_image'][1]['thumb']."'></li>";
    $counter++;
}

    echo apply_filters('images_filter',$content);
```

Echo the normal HTML, apply the filters to the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the foreach loop.

```
foreach($images as $image){
   if ($counter <= $hide){ 
      $content .= "<li><img src='".$image['images_image'][1]['thumb']."'></li>";
      $counter++;
   }
   else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
foreach($images as $image) if($counter++ <= $hide) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Though it's better to use break; as Simon R said.